# Can't launch Qt Creator in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, paths, chroot, qt-creator, qt5

My environment initially had qt4 and Qt Creator seemed to work fine back then. I installed qt5 and after that Qt Creator does not launch anymore. Qt Creator works fine in my virtual machine however.

I tried to launch it from the terminal, but I got this error message:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50905) with this library (version 0x50a01)
```

Qt is also installed in a chroot environment. I found out that my Qt Creator 4.5.2 is based on Qt 5.10.1, but my installed Qt version is 5.9.5.

Results of `apt policy qtcreator` and `apt policy qt5-default` from my default Ubuntu 18.04 environment. qtcreator is installed in the top level environment. Only qt5 is installed in chroot.

```
$ apt policy qtcreator 
qtcreator:
  Installed: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2
$ apt policy qt5-default
qt5-default:
  Installed: 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Is Qt also installed in a chroot environment?

Comment: Yes Karel. Is it recommended not to install Qt in chroot?

Comment: It's OK, but be careful not to break anything in Ubuntu 18.04 while in the chroot environment.

Comment: Qtcreator is installed in top-level. Only qt5 is installed in chroot.

Answer (score 0):

qt5-default is version 5.9.5 in Ubuntu 18.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq qt5-default qtcreator
```

Qt5 usually should be installed in your regular filesystem, not in a chroot environment. That way applications that depend on Qt5 like Qt Creator will be able to recognize it automatically. Otherwise you must setup a new Qt version in Qt Creator.

#### Setting up new Qt versions

To add a Qt version:

1. Select *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Build & Run* -> *Qt Versions* -> click *Add* button.
2. Select the Qt version to view and edit it.

   [image]
3. In the *Version name* field, edit the name that Qt Creator suggests for the Qt version.
4. In the *qmake location* field, you can change the qmake location. Change it to `/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake` as shown in the screenshot.
5. If the Qt version is for QNX, enter the path to your installed QNX SDK in the *QNX SDK* field.

Comment: Hi @karel, the command above just removed the qt5-default and qtcreator. I need to make Qt creator launch with qt5.9.5.

Comment: it gives the same error message.

Comment: What are the results of this command: `qtchooser -l` ? It should be like `4 5 default qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu qt4 qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu qt5`

Comment: yes karel. The result is 4 5 default qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu qt4 qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu qt5.

Comment: What are the results of `apt policy qtcreator` ? The first two lines should be `qtcreator: Installed: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2`

Comment: Here's the result:
qtcreator:
  Installed: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 4.5.2-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Does Qt Creator launch with this command: `/usr/bin/qtcreator` ?

Comment: The same error message shows. Thanks Karel for the help.

Comment: Ubuntu shows/hides hidden files/directories (files/directories which start with a `.` character) with the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+H. Browse in Files file manager to Home -> .config -> QtProject and rename everything in the *QtProject* directory including the *qtcreator* directory by adding the suffix `.bak` to the end of its name. Then from the terminal run `/usr/bin/qtcreator` again and Qt Creator will rewrite a new user profile without deleting any of the backup .bak files that you made.

Comment: Hi Karel. /home/user/.config/QtProject/qtcreator folder is empty.

Comment: @LostDeveloper Everything in `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/` can be manually regenerated with their defaults except for some files which I already told you to backup in the qtcreator.bak directory. See my updated answer.

Comment: would that affects if I installed the QT in a chroot environment?

Comment: If you installed Qt in a chroot environment, then QT Creator profile may not be able to find Qt in order to automatically regenerate its profile if it is deleted because Qt Creator is expecting to find Qt in the default location, not in a chroot environment. Maybe you have Qt path issues. This is what VMs are good for.

Comment: Thanks Karel. I guess that explains why it works fine in my Virtual Machine.

Comment: I have to install qt5 in chroot distro for building.